# Pandas resample using a text column

Tags: python, pandas

thanks for taking the time to read this!
I have a question regarding pandas. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
                       close      high       low      open    volume       symbol
date                                                                           
2020-07-20 11:40:00     2.110     2.280     2.110     2.270  170620.0     A7L.L
2020-07-20 11:40:00     3.740     3.740     3.740     3.740     130.0   ALCJ.PA
2020-07-20 11:40:00    29.350    29.800    29.300    29.700    1060.0  ALCRB.PA
2020-07-20 11:41:00    29.800    29.800    29.800    29.800     117.0  ALCRB.PA
2020-07-20 11:40:00     3.340     3.345     3.330     3.330   10377.0  ALGAU.PA
```

These are stock quotes which are collected every minute. I would like resample these quotes into daily candles, so resample to '1D'. If i loop over every symbol i can do it with:

```
df=df.resample('1D').agg({
            'high' : 'max',
            'low': 'min',
            'open' : 'first',
            'close': 'last',
            'volume' : 'sum'
        })
```

but because of multiple reasons I would like to do it in 1 resample instead of 2000 individual ones. How can I resample, aggregating on symbol level in a timeframe of 1 day?

I tried:

```
df=df.groupby('ric').resample('1D').agg({
            'high' : 'max',
            'low': 'min',
            'open' : 'first',
            'close': 'last',
            'volume' : 'sum'
        })
```

But that didnt work.
Could anyone help me out here?
Thanks!

Comment: There is some error? What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 0):

For me your solution working, maybe is necessary upgrade pandas:

```
df1=(df.groupby('symbol').resample('1D').agg({
            'high' : 'max',
            'low': 'min',
            'open' : 'first',
            'close': 'last',
            'volume' : 'sum'
        }))
print (df1)
                       high    low   open  close    volume
symbol   date                                             
A7L.L    2020-07-20   2.280   2.11   2.27   2.11  170620.0
ALCJ.PA  2020-07-20   3.740   3.74   3.74   3.74     130.0
ALCRB.PA 2020-07-20  29.800  29.30  29.70  29.80    1177.0
ALGAU.PA 2020-07-20   3.345   3.33   3.33   3.34   10377.0
```

Alternative with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df2=(df.groupby(['symbol', pd.Grouper(freq='1D')]).agg({
            'high' : 'max',
            'low': 'min',
            'open' : 'first',
            'close': 'last',
            'volume' : 'sum'
        }))
print (df2)
                       high    low   open  close    volume
symbol   date                                             
A7L.L    2020-07-20   2.280   2.11   2.27   2.11  170620.0
ALCJ.PA  2020-07-20   3.740   3.74   3.74   3.74     130.0
ALCRB.PA 2020-07-20  29.800  29.30  29.70  29.80    1177.0
ALGAU.PA 2020-07-20   3.345   3.33   3.33   3.34   10377.0
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I dont know why the first method didnt work for me, but your second solution does the trick! :)